# How to push an image into an arra and check if image is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display a random image and once this image is displayed it is moved to another array, if the new random image is in the second array then it will repeat the function to get a new image. My code is as follows

```
var correctAnswer
var image
var images = new Array(10)
images[0] = "Bridleway.png"
images[1] = "Bus.png"
images[2] = "Footpath.png"
images[3] = "House.png"
images[4] = "Park.png"
images[5] = "Pillar.png"
images[6] = "Road.png"
images[7] = "Train.png"
images[8] = "Worship.png"
images[9] = "Youth.png"
//selecting a random image
var usedImages = new Array()
function getRandomImage() {
    image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
    if (image in usedImages)
        getRandomImage();
   else
    return image;
}

function displayRandomImage() {
    correctAnswer = document.getElementById("randomImage");
    correctAnswer.src = getRandomImage();
    usedImages.push(correctAnswer.src)
```

Comment: `in` is used for searching the properties of an object, not the values. Use `usedImages.indexOf(image) > -1`.

Comment: Would this go in the if statement of the function getRandomImage()?

Comment: It's better to use a loop than recursion for this. When most of the images are used, you're going to keep trying lots of times before you find one that isn't used. You also need a check for all the images being used, otherwise it will repeat forever.

Comment: Yes, that's where it goes. It does what you thought you were doing with `image in usedImages`. Isn't that obvious from the documentation?

Comment: A better way to do this whole thing is to randomly shuffle the images array, then use them in order, wrapping around when you get to the end.

Comment: I have tried implementing this, im not sure if I've done it correctly my code I now if "(usedImages.indexOf(image))", now it doesn't display an image

Comment: Can't you read what I wrote? You left out `> -1`.

Comment: Sorry, late night. I put in the >-1 and it is now displaying the image but they're still repeating

Comment: The problem is that `correctAnswer.src` contains the full URL, not just the filenames that are in `usedImages`.

Comment: Would pushing in image work instead then?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: BTW, you should remember to declare local variables with `var`. Global variables can cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (image in usedImages)
```

to:

```
if (usedImages.indexOf(image) != -1)
```

`x in y` tests if `x` is one of the property names of the object `y`, it doesn't search the values of an array.

`y.indexOf(x)` returns the position of `x` in the array `y`. You can't use it as a boolean, because it returns `0` for the first element (which is falsey), and `-1` when the element isn't found (which is truthy). That's why you have to compare the result with `-1`.

The other problem is that when you retrieve `correctAnswer.src`, it will contain the full URL of the image, not just the filename, so it won't match what's in `images`. You should push the filename by itself.

```
function displayRandomImage() {
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("randomImage");
    var image = getRandomImage();
    correctAnswer.src = image;
    usedImages.push(image);
}
```